# can not insert datum using preparestatement

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I am trying to insert datum into mysql database using prepareStatement but its shows error like

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.sql.PreparedStatement to 
>    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement

Below is my code:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>


           <%

               try
                   {
                      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","");
                      // Statement st=connection.createStatement();
                      PreparedStatement st=null;
                      String Eid = request.getParameter("Eid");
                      String Rpswd=request.getParameter("Rpswd");
                      String uType=request.getParameter("uType");

                     // String query="insert into login_table(`uid`,`pswd`,`user_type`)  values('"+Eid+"','"+Rpswd+"','"+uType+"')";
    String query="insert into login_table(`uid`,`pswd`,`user_type`)  values(?,?,?)";
                       st = con.prepareStatement(query);
                       st.setString(1,Eid);
                       st.setString(2,Rpswd);
                       st.setString(3,uType);


                           // int i= st.executeUpdate(query);

                         int i= st.executeUpdate();


                      }
                 catch(Exception e)
                              {
                                 e.printStackTrace();
                               }

                   %>

</body>
</html>
```

Which is getting the error on`st = con.prepareStatement(query);`.

Help me. Where am I wrong?

**Note :** This the first time I am using `preparedstatement` from `CreateStatement` so suggest me which one is good for code?.

Comment: are you sure this `<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>` is the only import statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix your imports and replace

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
```

by

```
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
```

You should never use mysql-specific classes in your code. The standard JDBC classes are all you need.

Regarding the use aof prepared stataments, yes, it should be used every time you need to pass parameters to a query. It's a matter of robustness and of security (read about SQL injection attacks).

But JDBC code, and scriptlets in general, have nothing to do in JSPs. JSPs are view components, whose job is to generate HTML. They're not data access components. These should be written in Java and accessed from a controller servlet.

Comment: no! its not working.its shows error like "The import java.sql.PreparedStatement collides with another import statement"

Comment: That's because you imported java.sql.*. Then remove the import of com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement, that you don't need.

Comment: now i am imported only 
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %> but same error!

Comment: Then the error doesn't come from this JSP, or the JSP contains code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: sorry!i forgot to remove  <%@page import=" com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement" %>. its working fine now thanks dude.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
```

and replace with

`import java.sql.PreparedStatement;`